# How to access images loaded from css in Qt Webkit (java)

Tags: java, qt, webkit

In Qt WebKit you can call QWebFrame.renderTreeDump() to see the render tree. For images in html

```
<img src=...>
```

you get something like:

```
RenderImage {IMG} at (0,0) size 174x71
```

However, there is no render information for images loaded from ccs (backgrounds etc). Is there a way to access these? I'd also like to be get the urls of loaded images too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just started exploring QT/WebKit for work; in version 4.6 they have expanded considerably the API, it's now possible to access the DOM of a loaded document. The `QWebElement` class has a `styleProperty` getter that allows you to read the corresponding CSS property. For reading e.g. the background image of the body:

```
QWebElement body = main_frame->findFirstElement("body");
QString img = body.styleProperty("background-image", QWebElement::ComputedStyle);
```

For the full API see [QtWebKit Module reference documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtwebkit.html).

Comment: ok great, I'll check it out. I'm actually in a Java environment and using jambi. I understand that they're not continuing with development  of jambi beyond 4.5, which is annoying, as it's pretty damn good.

Comment: Oh, I totally missed the "Java" tag; unfortunately the DOM API has been introduced in QT 4.6...